# wrong when using document in VScode

Tags: reactjs, dom, visual-studio-code

I'm using React and I want to use document.querySelector in componentDidMount.

The code I wrote can run correctly in browser.

Here is my code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
      console.log(e.key);
    })
  }
  componentDidUnMount() {
    document.querySelector('#text').removeEventListener('keyup');
  }
```

`e.key` can be shown in browser. But VScode just shows it is error.
Questions just showed in `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUnMount()`. It says that object may be 'null'. I want to know how to cancel this error.

Comment: There is [no `componentDidUnMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount)

Comment: But document in componentDidMount also wrong.

Comment: `querySelector` returns `null` when there are no matches

Comment: I have run this correctly in browser.I'm sure I have got dom.But it just shows 'may be null' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it the wrong way, react uses handlers to know what to do when some event takes place. Event may be onChange, onKeyUp, onKeyDown.

Working example below for the functionality using React.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  handleLoginKeyUp = e => {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
  };
  render() {
    return <input type="text" onKeyUp={this.handleLoginKeyUp} />;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks. I just want to try this document way to achieve my requirements.So I can not use document in React.Component?